# PyQt5 как сделать срабатывание элементов

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtnetwork, qnetworkaccessmanager

нажатие на кнопку потом отправки post и вывод в элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял, что хотите сделать, попробую угадать. Попробуйте пример ниже. Прокомментирован по тексту.

```
'''   HTTP POST request
QNetworkAccessManager in PyQt

В этом примере мы отправляем данные на веб-страницу.
Пример отправляет запрос на сайт тестирования 
https://httpbin.org/post, 
который отправляет данные обратно в формате JSON.
'''

import sys
import json  
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.name = QLineEdit()
        self.name.setPlaceholderText("Введите Ваше имя")
        self.age  = QLineEdit()
        self.age.setPlaceholderText("Введите Ваше возраст")
        self.labelName = QLabel()
        self.labelAge  = QLabel()

        self.btn = QPushButton("Отправить на сайт")
        self.btn.pressed.connect(self.doRequest)

        layout.addWidget(self.name)
        layout.addWidget(self.age)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelName)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelAge)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)        

    def doRequest(self):   
        # Согласно спецификации, мы кодируем данные, отправленные в QByteArray.
        data = QtCore.QByteArray()
        data.append("name={}&".format(self.name.text()))
        data.append("age={}".format(self.age.text()))

        url = "https://httpbin.org/post"
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        # Мы указываем тип кодировки application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
        req.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader, 
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.handleResponse)
        self.nam.post(req, data)    


    def handleResponse(self, reply):
        print(reply)
        er = reply.error()

        if er == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
            # В методе обработчика мы считываем данные ответа и декодируем его. 
            # Со встроенным модулем json мы извлекаем опубликованные данные.
            bytes_string = reply.readAll()

            # и декодируем его. 
            json_ar = json.loads(str(bytes_string, 'utf-8'))
            # Со встроенным модулем json мы извлекаем опубликованные данные.
            data = json_ar['form']

            self.labelName.setText("Name: {}".format(data['name']))
            self.labelAge.setText("{}".format(data['age']))
            print('Name: {0}'.format(data['name']))
            print('Age:  {0}'.format(data['age']))
        else:
            print("Error occurred: ", er)
            print(reply.errorString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)           
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я понял как срабатывают кнопки